# AWS Cognito AdminLinkProviderForUser - User Pool Account and Facebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, identity

Our setup is:

- Email/Password account creation or Facebook Sign In

I am able to create both successfully independent of each other with AWS Cognito.

The problem I want to solve is if a user has an Email/Password account first, and clicks Facebook Sign In, I want them to link and prompt the user to confirm they had access to the Email/Password account.

Once the user confirms that going forward, they should be able to either Facebook Sign In or Email/Password login to access and adjust the same account.

Facebook User in Cognito User Pool:
- [Facebook User in Cognito User Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULNQQ.png)

Email/Password User Linked in Cognito User Pool to Facebook User:
[Email/Password User Linked in Cognito User Pool to Facebook User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAtDQ.png)

I'm currently using the Pre Sign Up Trigger to Auto Verify Email, Confirm, and Link Account.  For Social (Facebook), I'm using:

```
GET amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Facebook&response_type=code then

POST amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

This works but I authenticate as the Facebook_*user* and my expectation (and want) is to authenticate as the link user at that point.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 19):

Ultimately, the answer was I was not removing Facebook_ from the userid.  So I was in theory linking my Cognito Email / Password to 'Facebook_USERID' not 'USERID.'

Once I made that change, I was able to authenticate as 1 account linked.

```
// Get Email
        var params = {
          UserPoolId: 'YOUR_USER_POOL',
          AttributesToGet: ['sub','email'],
          Filter: "email = \"" + event.request.userAttributes.email + "\""
        }
        cognito.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
            else {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(event.userName);
                if(data != null && data.Users != null && data.Users[0] != null)
                {
                  console.log(data.Users[0].Username);
                  var params = {
                    DestinationUser: { 
                      ProviderAttributeValue: data.Users[0].Username,
                      ProviderName: 'Cognito'
                    },
                    SourceUser: { 
                      ProviderAttributeName: 'Cognito_Subject',
                      ProviderAttributeValue: event.userName.split("_")[1],
                      ProviderName: 'Facebook'
                    },
                    UserPoolId: 'YOUR_USER_POOL'
                  };
                  cognito.adminLinkProviderForUser(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
                  });
                }
            }
        });
```

**Update - 4/24/2020**

We added a Native Account for anyone who signs up, so that we don't run into the problem.  They just have to activate/reset their password if they try to sign in via Native.  The below script is in our Pre-Sign Up Trigger Lambda Function:

```
  {
    // ExternalProvider (ie. Social)
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
      // Create Native User Always
      var params = {
        ClientId: backendClientIds[event.userPoolId],
        Password: generatePassword(),
        Username: event.request.userAttributes.email
      };
      cognito.signUp(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { 
          console.log('cognito.signUp:');
          console.log(err, err.stack); 
          if(err.code === 'UsernameExistsException')
          {
            // Get and Link Existing User
            getUsersAndLink(event.userPoolId, event.request.userAttributes.email, event);
          }
        }
        else {
          console.log('cognito.signUp:');
          console.log(data);
          if(data.UserConfirmed)
          {
            // Link Newly Created User
            linkUser(data.UserSub, event);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

If helpful here is the whole lambda code: https://pastebin.com/4cyF9Nkw

Comment: How did you handle the opposite situation? a user logs in using Fb first and then the same user with the same email creates a Email/Password account.

Comment: @Jun711 - We use a Lambda function to auto create a Native account, so that you always have "both" a Native Account and a Social Account when signed up/in with Facebook.  The Lambda function is in the Pre-Sign Up Trigger.  See code in main post above.

Comment: @Jun711 I hope that helps!

Comment: I see. I am using Pre-Sign Up Trigger, do you return the signUp event after linking the account? I tried with and without returning the event, both give me a different error in frontend when I use Amplify federatedSignIn.

Comment: I don't utilize the signUp event's return per se.  We are using .NET SDK, so whats the Cognito trigger fires we are further along than that

Comment: Sorry, I meant the pre-sign up trigger event by 'signUp event'. ok, I will pass the trigger event on too like how you do it. On the other hand, I tried to link an External_Provider account after a social media login but it doesn't allow me to do that. It only allows linking before an External_Provider user entry is created. I guess your way of auto-creating a Native account is the way to go. Thanks, Dan!

Comment: Welcome, @Jun711 it was a frustrating issue until I got through it :).

Comment: Hi Dan. I have a question. Once you link the Facebook account with the Native account. How are you getting access/id/refresh Tokens using Facebook login? I can't find this anywhere in AWS Cognito Documentation.

Comment: @Xon - Depending what you're asking, but I ran into something similar.  The first login/sign up always "fails" (sort of) because you basically just get access, but aren't allowed to act as the user yet. You need to make a call to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html and that will return a access_token, which you can then act as the user :)

Comment: I'm using the AWS Amplify Auth library and I linked two accounts successfully. When I use the federatedSignIn call, I'm still not getting the cognito user. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @MayowaDaniel, sadly I'm not using the library other than some scripts in Lambda

Comment: @dan, any chance you can paste your whole lambda code? Or share a Gist of it? :P

Comment: @KevinWang , sure thing buddy

Code: https://pastebin.com/4cyF9Nkw

I removed 2 areas: (1) the values in our userpool/backend client id (2) the code in our generate password, enjoy!

Comment: Hi @Dan, Any occurrence of `Already found an entry for username...` on your end? Using the same strategy you used I facing this error at the first user login.